# Taking audio frequency and picking out peaks (Peak Detection)

Tags: fft, audio, python, peak-detection

So I have a unique challenge. I want to take an audio file, and pick out the peaks in the samples and plot that onto a graph. Each point based on the amplitude/pitch(?) will be represented as either a small dot (lower amplitude) or a bigger dot (higher amplitude).

So if I had to look at a drum track, I should notably see big dots where the drum is hit, but smaller dots when a cymbal is hit.

From a technology stack perspective, I am using Python - and using a Library called Aubio (although I am not sure if there is a better library out there).

**EDIT**:

Forgive me on the lingo - very new at this audio stuff.  Okay so the issue I have currently is that I have a waveform graph that shows the samples over time using a standard sampling technique.

But I found an article on [Peak detection](https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/spectrum/PeakFindingandMeasurement.htm), which is exactly what I am looking for (I think).

The challenge I have now is pulling those peak values out via Python and Aubio and plotting them on a Graph.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to signals.SE; this is a bit hard to answer, because you (ab)use the word "frequency" for different things. Because of that (or maybe, because I'm generally a bit of a confused person), I simply don't get the picture you're aiming for. So, we need to clarify first: "peaks in the frequencies" <-- I think you might be thinking of maxima in a power spectral density (PSD) plot? Can you confirm that? "Each point based on the frequency" <-- you mean you arrange points on an axis that means "higher frequencies to the right, lower frequencies to the left"? your "bigger"/"lower" …

Comment: … notation isn't clear, either: you mean "higher frequency" (as in: 10 kHz is higher than 100 Hz), or do you mean "higher amplitude at that frequency" (as in: the sound at 100 Hz is much louder than the one at 10 kHz). What is a "symbol" in this context?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the questions. Please see above edit I made to the post. In essence I am trying to create the following [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dx5eqs7xkm9ci81/example.png?dl=0) (orange dots when peaks happen)

Comment: Drums and cymbals don't really have a frequency or pitch.  Are drums and cymbals the only thing you need to detect?  Are they always from the same drum kit?

Comment: I am using a STEMS file, which has different tracks embedded into one 1 (Drums on a different track to bass, separate to melody, etc).  What I found so far is that if I use peak detection, I might be able to represent the output the way I need it [link](https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/spectrum/PeakFindingandMeasurement.htm)  Just need to figure out how I do that in Python.

Comment: you can try this link.We need to find the x-axis indices for the peaks in order to determine where the peaks are located.
https://plot.ly/python/peak-finding/

Answer (score 9):

I found the answer finally. I found a great article that explains many different libraries that can be utilized for peak detection.  I now have the peaks I am really interested in, and can now create the output I am requiring.

[Finding Peaks in Python](https://github.com/MonsieurV/py-findpeaks)